# SQL date not relative

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which i store every 15 minutes result of a cron job, which is nothing more than a timestamp, a population number and an id.

I am trying to query it as following.

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(`population`),0) AS population, DATE(`time`) AS date
FROM `swg_servertracker`
WHERE `time` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(`time`)
DESC
LIMIT 7
```

[image]

What it does it creates an daily average, and grabs the last 7 entries. Sadly in was not in the right order, so i flipped it to ascending. My problem is when i inverse (`asc`) it, it skips today, and goes back an extra day (today is the 3rd of october, which is not taken in the equation when i use the ascending)

I tried to set the where statement to just now - interval 168 hours (which is also 7 days but then relative back) which had no result either on this. Still it skips today and just goes back 7 days from on yesterday.

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(`population`),0) AS population, DATE(`time`) AS date 
FROM `swg_servertracker` 
WHERE `time` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 168 HOUR 
GROUP BY DATE(`time`) 
ASC 
LIMIT 7
```

[image: Result is skipping today]

So is there a way I can take today in account as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You select 8 records instead 7 records. If you want to select 7 latest records, you must use "greater than" sign instead "greater than or equal" sign.

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(`population`),0) AS population, DATE(`time`) AS date 
FROM `swg_servertracker` 
WHERE `time` > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(`time`) 
ASC 
LIMIT 7
```

Comment: Almost correct, i fixed it due to the remark you made that i select 8 records. I did use your code with a slight alteration in the interval, switching it 6 days. That did the trick. Never realized that i selected a day more as I thought today was in the interval.

Answer (score 0):

- You can get the result-set in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and do a sorting on the results again.
- Note that, [in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html), Aliases defined in the `Select` clause can be used in `Group By`, `Having` and `Order By` clauses. So, I have aliased `DATE(time)` to avoid re-computation in `Group by` and `Order By`.

You can do this instead:

```
SELECT dt.population, 
       dt.date1 AS date 
FROM (
      SELECT ROUND(AVG(`population`),0) AS population, 
             DATE(`time`) AS date1
      FROM `swg_servertracker`
      WHERE `time` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
      GROUP BY date1 
      ORDER BY date1 DESC
      LIMIT 7
    ) AS dt 
ORDER BY dt.date1 ASC
```